# Why we not use Dynamic p-value instead of the fixed value?

Tags: p-value

Why we always use a fixed p-value like 0.05 or 0.01, I think we can use different p-value depends on the number of samples as well as probability or the event(In the coin flip experiment, it would be 0.5) to get a better estimate answer.

Comment: Need to be more specific. Whose probability? What kind of event?

Comment: It's very easy to become biased and adjust thresholds to better suit your data.

Comment: That is why we need the formula to make everyone use it to avoid adjust thresholds, right?